# The project file is not bound to source control after modifying .csproj files when upgrading to ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, version-control, azure-devops

After upgrading a solution to ASP.NET Core 2.0 I needed to completely change the structure of all of my .csproj files.

After closing and restarting Visual Studio I got a notification about solution binding for all of my .csproj files.

> The project file
>   C:\Projects\MyProj\src\MyProj\client\WebAPI\WebAPI.csproj is not bound
>   to source control, but the solution contains source control binding
>   information for it.
>
> Do you want to open the project using source control binding
>   information from the solution or open it as unbound and fix the
>   solution file?

When I select Use solution binding it adds a bunch of source control stuff to each individual .csproj and when I choose to remove solution binding. When comparing the .sln file to my original .sln file now it removed all of the solution projects from

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
        SccNumberOfProjects = 1
        SccEnterpriseProvider = {4BB58BB2-18FA-4B8B-95B4-32BBF27B184B}
        SccTeamFoundationServer = https://mycompany.visualstudio.com/
        SccLocalPath0 = .
```

There used to be 10 Projects listed in this section. Is this a problem? It is strange that I don't see any source control symbols next to the files in each project within the solution. However if I make a change to one of the files and go to pending changes it still recognizes that it needs to be checked in.

**UPDATE:**
When moving to 2.0 I removed the following lines from my .csproj files;

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Are these still required when using VSTS? When I add them back everything works as it did. If there is a cleaner/newer way to avoid using these lines please let me know.

Comment: How did you change the solution to .net core 2.0 and what did you change the .csproj files structure? And please also check in vs source control explorer if all the .csproj files are showed. If not, you should add the missing .csproj file(s) to source control.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I just did a rollback to an older version in source control.